# Error while creating Android Emulator in eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator

I tried to create an emulator for Samsung Galaxy S4,but I am getting the following error.
 I searched in SO but didnt find any solution.

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD_for_Galaxys4'
Failed to create Context 0x3005
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as emulators go [genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) is the best around.

I strongly recommend using that instead of built in emulators.